# vb.net httpwebrequest times out accessing https server

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, ssl, https

I have a vb.net application that accesses an https server for backing up files.

It all works fine when I run the application on one of my development machines, either from inside Visual Studio or as a deployed exe, but as soon as I deploy the application to a client machine, the httpwebrequest / response times out.

The only common link I can see is that the development machines both run Visual Studio and the client machines don't. What am I missing? I have literally spent days trying to resolve this now.

Comment: Does this client browse via a proxy server? It could be that the network is blocking the connection.

Comment: No. I've also tried it on a non Visual Studio machine on my local network and same problem occurs.